# Confusion on Triangle Diagram and contact terms (from Mark Srednicki' book)

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am confused on some identities in Mark Srednicki's QFT book, section76. Let $j^{\mu}=\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi$ and $j^{\nu}_A=\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma_5\psi$ be $U(1)$ and $U(1)_A$ current, respectively. Then we have three identities (see eqs. (76.17)-(76.19) in the book)

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\partial_{\mu} \langle j^{\nu}(x)j^{\nu}(y)j^{\rho}_A(z) \rangle=0  \cr
&\partial_{\nu} \langle j^{\nu}(x)j^{\nu}(y)j^{\rho}_A(z) \rangle=0  \cr
&\partial_{\rho} \langle j^{\nu}(x)j^{\nu}(y)j^{\rho}_A(z) \rangle=0  
\end{aligned}
$$

In the next, it says

> Note that there are no contact terms in eqs. (76.17)-(76.19), because both $j^{\mu}$ and $j^{\mu}_A$ are invariant under both $U(1)$ transformation.

This is my confusion: why does such invariance give vanishing contact terms?

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524316). Although it doesn't have an answer, there is a helpful comment by Anonjohn, saying *"The right hand side of the ward identity is the contact terms. But each contact term is the variation of the operator under the U(1) gauge(axial) symmetry times a delta function. Since the currents themselves are invariants under the symmetry, the contact terms vanish"*